# PineScript collecting measuring tool data

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Is there any way in PineScript I can collect all that short and long position  data I get from the prediction/measuring tool and have it displayed in a table?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qirFD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get any data from the measurement tool. However, you can calculate those yourself if you know what your entry, stop loss and take profit prices are.

[image]